# Remove vertices that are not in the frame

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh

I'm creating a rather long (234 frames) animation with a giant landscape as background/environment. Since my computer (it is a laptop actually) is rather slow in terms of rendering, I would like to speed up this process as much as possible. The scene has now already over 1 million vertices and I expect this number to at least double as I plan to add a forest covering most of the landscape (low-poly trees like seen in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/72LPW4S8bns) on youtube) as well as fog/clouds everywhere. There is camera motion in the shot, but a lot (I estimate almost about 2/5) of the vertices of the landscape are never in the frame.

I assume removing them would save some render time (probably not much, but this will ad up for each frame). This could be done manually which would however need some time. Is there any process in blender to automate this process?

Comment: Removing geometry will effect the quality of your image. Cycles is a path tracer, meaning any object nearby (not visible in the camera frustum) will still affect the appearance of all other objects. The only thing you can to is decimating the geometry, which will reduce render times *but* it's not that much as you'd probably expect: [Does decimate an object helps cycles rendering faster in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175628/31447)

Comment: Also related: [How to prevent things from out of sight rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139126/how-to-prevent-things-from-out-of-sight-rendering)